# Websocket HTML5 multiple Two player games on Server

Tags: node.js, html, browser, websocket, server

I already did some research and wasn't able to find any specific answer on this topic.

I try to make a html5 + websocket multiplayer based game, but the tutorials and articles I found mostly focused on multiplayer games which connects more than two player on a Server.

I just want to know if it is possible two create a game which connects two clients via the Server. Any other who wants to play create a kind of lobby, Waits till a player connects and then the game starts seperatly at the same time the other game runs on the same server.

I am using socket.io and node.js. I already have done the raw game, which lets player connect to. And this time two boxes which can be controlled by the Clients.

Any tips or hints would be awesome!

Comment: Please describe what has been done so far to solve the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible. However, you will need to implement such a lobby mechanism yourself. You might want to read on socket.io rooms (http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/), they might help, though are not necessary for a lobby system.

Comment: Thank you. Actually this was the solution, I searched for!